# LCOV is not generating coverage information for header files

Tags: gcov, lcov

for one of the header file lcov is not generating coverage report(information) header file, contains class with function prototypes and shared pointer declaration, why lcov is not generating report for header files
example
class a : public b
{
public:
int add(int c, int d)override;
int sub(int d, int e)overide;

std::shared_ptr members;
}

we tried with different optimization techniques